# Symfony injected Doctrine Manager instance to controller method arguments

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony4

In Controller, you can define a update action with following:

```
    /**
     * @Route("/product/edit/{id}")
     */
    public function updateAction(Product $product)
    {
     // product is auto select from database by id and inject to controller action.
    }
```

The auto injection is very convenient, But how to inject the Doctrine Manager instance to controller action, it would be more convenient without create Doctrine Manager instance manually. like following:

```
    /**
     * @Route("/product/edit/{id}")
     */
    public function updateAction(Product $product, ObjectManager $em)
    {
       $product->setName("new name");
       $em->flush();
    }
```

instead of long coding:

```
/**
 * @Route("/product/edit/{id}")
 */
public function updateAction($id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $product = $em->getRepository(Product::class)->find($id);

    if (!$product) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException(
            'No product found for id '.$id
        );
    }

    $product->setName('New product name!');
    $em->flush();

    return $this->redirectToRoute('app_product_show', [
        'id' => $product->getId()
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried Symfony4 yet, but based on official symfony documentation, there is action-based dependency injection, so you should be able to use services by declaring service interface as argument on your action.

https://symfony.com/doc/4.1/controller.html#controller-accessing-services

> If you need a service in a controller, just type-hint an argument with its class (or interface) name. Symfony will automatically pass you the service you need:

So in your case it should look like this:

```
/**
  * @Route("/product/edit/{id}")
  */
public function updateAction(Product $product, EntityManagerInterface $em)
{
    $product->setName("new name");
    $em->flush();
}
```